# Delete Table record having foreign key constraint Magento 2

Tags: magento2, module

in my custom module, I have two tables with 1 to many relationships. Now in my admin UI Grid whenever I delete the record it does not delete it.

My question is how i can delete record from both tables at once. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

set `ON DELETE CASCADE` when you set `FOREIGN KEY` in your second table.

Comment: in installSchema.php?

Comment: Yes in installSchema

Comment: it is already there. can u please paste code of Delete.php
https://prnt.sc/pt51ch

Comment: No need to add an extra code of delete it will automatically delete record from the child table.